# How to change the Facebook payment payout method?

Tags: facebook

I have created a Facebook app but now I want to modify the Facebook Payout method (I want to change it from a Paypal company account to my bank account). When I logged in the developer dashboard I found it's not allowed to make any changes.

This is what I saw:

[image: Nowhere to modify the payout method]

I was redirected to StackExchange from the support page of Facebook Developers, is there any one from Facebook can help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/payout_faq/#change

This link answers the following frequently asked questions:

How do I specify who receives the payout from my app?

When does Facebook pay out?

Which countries can Facebook Payments pay out to?

How do I change the payee for an app?

What does 30% revenue share cover?

What tax laws apply to virtual sales made through Facebook Payments?

Does the 30% fee include taxes?

How does Facebook equip developers to comply with local tax laws?